# How to make Python sleep until Excel query has refreshed without disabling background refresh?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I have some queries in an xlsx file that reads data from a csv file. I want to create a Python script that refreshes all queries in the said xlsx file. When refreshing all by clicking on the "Refresh All" button in Excel, it takes around 40-50 seconds.

As of now, the program sleeps for 60 seconds after it refreshes the Excel queries. This works. However, I would like to have the possibility to switch out the csv file, so that the time it takes is not fixed but can take any time between 5 seconds to 10 minutes.

```
path_queries = #folder name where the excel file exists
file_name = #the xlsx file name

xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")

xlapp.Visible = True

# Open the workbook in said instance of Excel
wb = xlapp.Workbooks.open(path_queries + '//' + file_name)

# Refresh all data connections.
wb.RefreshAll()

time.sleep(60)
#xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()

#xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False

wb.Save()

wb.Close()
# Quit
xlapp.Quit()
```

If I do not have the sleep line, then Excel will close before it has refreshed. The function CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone() also only seems to works if I disable background refresh in Excel, but then the refresh would take up to four times as long (Which is not acceptable since I have several of these file I would like to update. The total time it takes to refresh all xlsx files is about 1 hour).

Is there a way to refresh a workbook in Excel with Python without sleeping or disabling background updates? Or, is there a way to sleep just until the refresh has completed? Thanks!

Comment: I am not entirely sure of what are You asking since I am a bit confused about the background processes, are they processes that occur in python script? because You could try using threading or find a way to check if refresh has happened (don't know how)

Comment: @Matiiss Background refreshes is a setting in excel that allows for several queries in it to be refreshed simultaneously (if applicable). Say if I have five queries in my excel workbook that are in some ways built on each other. If background refreshes would be turned off, then the second query would wait for the first query to refresh before it starts to refresh. This takes a long time, and is the answer most to the other questions on StackOverflow proposed. I would like to find a way to check if the queries have been refreshed without  only allowing one thread, but several.

Comment: I have no idea on how to check whether a query is finished, also what is background refresh is that an Excel option? also what does `RefreshAll()` do? can You give the definition? also I have no understanding of win32 so I can only give You some conceptual ideas